# acces each label id in dojo

Tags: dojo

> `a=dojo.query('label');`

by this command i get

```
<label id=​"labelforclientname">​
                Client name
            ​</label>​
, 
<label id=​"labelforphysical">​
                Physical 
                ​</label>​
, 
<label id=​"labelforpostal">​
                Postal 
                ​</label>​
, 
<label id=​"labelfortele">​
                Telephone No 
                ​</label>​
, 
<label id=​"labelforfax">​
                Fax No
                ​</label>​
, 
<label id=​"labelformail">​
                Email
                ​</label>​
, 
<label id=​"labelforaddress">​
                Address to :
            ​</label>​
```

that is all the label in my form

now i want to access each label id. is it possbile in dojo ?

Answer (score 0):

If you just want an array with `id`s then `map()` is the most straightforward way:

```
// map
var ids1 = dojo.query('label').map(function(label) {
    return label.id
});
```

or use `forEach`:

```
// forEach
var ids2 = [];
dojo.query("label").forEach(function(label) {
    // do whatever you need with a label here
    ids2.push(label.id);          
});
```

See it in action at jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/phusick/nfMGC/

[`dojo/query`](http://livedocs.dojotoolkit.org/dojo/query) returns [`dojo/NodeList`](http://dojotoolkit.org/api/1.8/dojo/NodeList) which is an *array-like object which adds syntactic sugar for chaining*. You can use many of its methods, like `filter`, `style`, `toggleClass` etc. For additional details see [Using dojo/query](http://dojotoolkit.org/documentation/tutorials/1.8/using_query/) and [NodeList Extensions](http://dojotoolkit.org/documentation/tutorials/1.8/nodelist_extensions/) tutorials.

Answer (score 0):

You can also get access to the labels with this way:

```
require(["dojo/dom"], function(dom){
    // fetch a node by id="someNode"
    var node = dom.byId("someNode");
});
```